# Django: UniqueConstraint Not Enforced

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to use a UniqueConstraint as follows:

```
class CitationVote(models.Model):
    user_who_voted = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.IntegerField(choices = [(-1, "down"), (1, "up")])
    timestamp_voted = models.DateTimeField()
    citation_id = models.ForeignKey('Citation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user_who_voted', 'citation_id'], name='one_vote_pp')]
```

Although the Django 3.0 docs do not mention any restriction on using UniqueConstraint with a Foreign Key (or Unique_Together, neither of which work in this example), the restriction is certainly not enforced in testing. I don't see anything in migrations either that indicate the constraint being enforced in Postgres.

For kicks, I changed the code to:

```
class CitationVote(models.Model):
    user_who_voted = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.IntegerField(choices = [(-1, "down"), (1, "up")])
    timestamp_voted = models.DateTimeField()
    citation_id = models.ForeignKey('Citation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['vote', 'timestamp_voted'], name='one_vote_pp')]
```

Alas, the same thing occurs (and yes, I drop the entire DB and recreate it fresh each time)-- no constraint enforced, nothing in migrations to suggest it would be after applying them.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `meta` class should be with a capital **M** thus it should be:

```py
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user_who_voted', 'citation_id'], name='one_vote_pp')
    ]
```

Your unique constraint looks fine otherwise.